# Why does changing Chart LINE properties in VBA do not work?

Tags: vba, excel

I copy-pasted an embedded chart into a new worksheet. I was able to change the source data but could not change the line weight and the color. I don't understand what is happening... great to get feedback! Here is my code:

```
        With .SeriesCollection(1)
            .Values = DP.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A18:A58")
            .XValues = DP.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C18:C58")
            .Format.Line.Weight = 1
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End With
```

SeriesCollection(1) has existing links which is replaced by those references/ranges. This changes the line color to 'AUTOMATIC' and excel assigns a very odd color which I want to change back to black. Unsure with what is happening. Help please!

Comment: what type is your `.SeriesCollection(1)`, is it for sure `xlLine` (4)?

Comment: Its scatter with just lines and no markers.

Comment: It worked in my original worksheet but when I copied it into a new worksheet via VBA, I could not change the line properties (using the code).